# How to create route/ingress for apps deployed via spring cloud data flow in kubernetes

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are working on setting up Spring cloud data flow in kubernetes cluster. Wanted to know how we can enable external access to deployed apps from outside the cluster.

We are basically migrating from PCF into kubernetes environment and PCF does have a domain i can specify, but i do not see an equivalent on a kubernetes deployment.

I saw a couple of references to using this deployer property

deployer..kubernetes:createLoadBalancer: true

But the external ip is in pending, there was also some reference about using
kubernetes.serviceType: NodePort

but do not see it affecting my deployment and deployer properties when viewed from scdf dashboard doesnt show a property for this one.

So basically, i would like to know how I can create a PCF route equivalent for k8s deployed pods of a stream definition deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example:
If you deploy a stream using the standard stream application http sink then you add `deployer.http.kubernetes.createLoadBalancer=true` to the deployment properties.
The application will be deployed with LoadBalancer type on the Service and will exposed an external address assuming your cluster has a load balancer attached.

Assuming the stream is named `httplogger` using `curl` and `jq` to extract the url will look like this:

```
JSON=$(curl -s $DATAFLOW_URL/runtime/streams/httplogger)
URL=$(jq -r '._embedded.streamStatusResourceList[0] | .applications._embedded.appStatusResourceList | .[] | select(.name == "http") | .instances._embedded.appInstanceStatusResourceList[0] | .attributes.url')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But our platform team do not want multiple load balancers spun up for every stream definition. So looking for a way to ensure some sort of ingress or service which can use metadata label keys and use its value to map to incoming attribute or some similar solution which can reduce overhead and not having to touch this service for every new stream definition that gets deployed

Comment: All this does is add LoadBalancer instead of NodePort or ClusterIP on the Service. So the installed LoadBalancer should create the route.

Comment: Take note that some loadbalancers will provide a hostname. Another way to obtain the address is: export SERVICE_URL="$(kubectl get svc --namespace default httplogger-http -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'):8080" or export SERVICE_URL="$(kubectl get svc --namespace default httplogger-http -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}'):8080" depending on what the specific loadbalancer is doing. use kubectl get svc --namespace default httplogger-http -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer}' to see what the loadbalancer produces.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try but our platform team doesnt like that each service might end up creating a LB and we are trying a custom proxy app to tide over this and not have to work on changing something everytime we deploy a stream